# flask run on 0.0.0.0 on specific page by default

Tags: python, flask

How do I run `flask` app directly to `0.0.0.0/input` page instead of "/"?

Is this possible?

Otherwise, what is best way to exclude "/" from showing?

```
@app.route("/")
def home():
    return 200

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0/input', port=int(os.getenv("FLASK_PORT", "8100")), debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redirect your root url:

```
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def home():
    return redirect(url_for("hello"))

@app.route("/hello")
def hello():
    return "<p>Hello</p>"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True)
```